# how can my android app find a file that was downloaded from PC?

Tags: android, download

I uploaded a file from PC to my android phone.
I want to open this file from within an app.
There are many sample codes to be found on the web but none work in my environment.
The app proposes several applications that can handle this intent, but all of them show a Download directory which is empty.
My code is:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are set.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `uploaded a file from PC to my android phone` How? Using a usb cable? Then you should know path of directory where you put the file. Please tell. Which Android version on phone? You should also request permission at runtime using some extra code.

Comment: `DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)` But you did not use the download manager so how should it know what you did? Better use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and let the user search for the file. No permissions needed at all.